# Perl search term

Tags: perl

I want to write the following statement as a Perl search expression:

Find all occurrences of the word "cat" followed by the word "dog" within 13 characters.

So for example the text "**cat**ajdwos **dog**qwzv" would be a result.

Do someone know how to do this?

Comment: Within 13 chars of what? (The start of `cat`? The end of `cat`? The end of the word starting with `cat`?)

Comment: What exactly do you want to obtain? (The positions of the words? The characters in between? All the matching characters starting with `cat` and ending with `dog`?)

Comment: And what about `catcatdogdog`. How many occurrences is that?

Comment: This looks a lot like homework. It also doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work...

```
$str = "sdfcatsdfdogffdfcatsdfjljlfflkfjflkjfdogsfsd";
@arr = $str =~ /(cat).{0,10}dog/sgi;
print join(',', @arr), "\n";
```

s to match over newlines, g to extract all matched instances, and i to ignore case.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'within 13', but I've assumed here that as many as 10 characters can separate the 't' in cat from the 'd' in dog.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a regular expression evaluated by the match operator. You'd use the `g` modifier of the match operator to find all occurrences.

```
while ($str =~ /...pattern.../g) {
   ...
}
```

Refer to your class notes on regular expressions to compose the pattern you need.